# Javascript Regex, re use a group to mach another group

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi guys I want re use the expression for capture other group

For example:

I need search `US $4.5-8.8` 
The structure is: **Part1-Part2**

The **part1** and the **part2** have the same code, I could use the part1 like group, and then re use in the part2

I've doned the expression until 4.5-XXXX

```
US \$([0-9]{1}(?=\.{1})\.{1}[0-9]+)(?=\-)\-
```

check in: https://regex101.com/r/E2MjWh/1

What should I do for re use the first group? It is easy in other lenguague, but I can't do it in javascript..

**PD: I need it in regex, not include javascript code like var... etc etc..**

Comment: You cannot recurse subpatterns, but you can define variables and build the pattern dynamically. Or use a single regex literal like [`/^US\s+\$(\d*\.?\d+)-(\d*\.?\d+)$/`](https://regex101.com/r/DbZvFs/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ohh, ok dude, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, have a look at your regex: the positive lookaheads are not really necessary there as they just require the same as the following consuming subpatterns. `(?=\.{1})\.{1}` means *require 1 dot immediately to the right of the current location and then match the dot, and `(?=\-)\-` has a similar meaning requiring and matching a `-` symbol.

Now, you ask if you can repeat the same part of a pattern using just the regex syntax. No, it is not possible in JS regex.

You may use the following regex to match the whole string like yours:

```
/US\s+\$(\d+\.\d+)-(\d+\.\d+)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cxMD4B/2). Sure, you may add word boundaries (to match `US` as a whole word) or anchors (to match the whole input  string) or replace the `\d+\.\d+` part with `\d*\.?\d+` (to match both integers or floats) to further enhance the pattern.

There is a way to shorten the pattern by placing the repetitive part into a variable and build the regex dynamically using the constructor notation:

```
var price = "\\d*\\.?\\d+";
var reg = new RegExp("US\\s+\\$(" + price + ")-(" + price + ")");
```

Add the required modifiers if necessary.